# how to get data from one activty to another several times Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i tried to make an basketball game with 2 activities.
one is the opening screen with a play button and when i press on play i build a pop up window that will give the user some inputs like player name , percentage form field and more some data. how can i do that after the user enter all the details at the pop up screen and press enter it will send the data to the arraylist in the MainActivity and its will pop up again (i need that the pop up will open 6 times - each time for each player. 6 players at all). can someone plz tell me because intent is not good here from the pop up. thanks

Comment: SharedPreferences, interfaces, static fields, database, there are serveral methods to do that. Best for you is dependent by actions, which you will do between display each dialog window.

Comment: What have you tried?  See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save the data somewhere preferably , you can use an SqLiteDatabase which saves the player information having playerId as a Primary field.

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to save all data in the database or shared preferences!

You can use a static class to store data or use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to interact with your classes.